# I can't connect to VPN, NetworkManager says "(nm-tray): Connection lost no longer connected to vpn" on Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: lubuntu, openvpn

How to fix it? I already tried to change openvpn - I was using tunnelbear and now I installed protonvpn. Thanks all who will try to help me. [here's the picture of issue:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkWuS.png)

Comment: Have you tried the manual - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/G/AdvancedNetworking.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just have done what is there and now it works :)

Comment: Please consider writing an answer (using the manual reference I provided please) with what you did, what fixed it, and in time you'll be able to accept it & gain some rep :)

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't visit this site since I've got your answer till now.

So, in general the problem was because my network manager didn't ask for a password while I tried to connect to VPN. And basically it's very easy to fix it, you just need to write this command in terminal (from manual): 
**nmcli con up id <VPN_name> --ask changing <VPN_name>**
With the actual VPN-name. Or:
**nm-applet**
Then you need to reboot your PC and after that try to connect to VPN again, it must ask for a password now.

Comment: Please add answer in the "Your Answer" section below. People can upvote it when they find it helpful (and you'll gain rep), you can accept it as the answer in time (you'll gain rep. plus the question can then be found by users seeking help)...  Currently this shows as an unanswered question (no answer yet has been provided).

Comment: sorry again for such a late answer! but it's done now :)

Answer (score 4):

[There's an open ticket for Lubuntu 20.04 discussing this very situation for nm-tray](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nm-tray/+bug/1886561), but from the guide it's clear that [nm-tray does not support password asking](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/G/AdvancedNetworking.html).

I solved switching from `nm-tray` to `nm-applet` in `Autostart`.

Go to `Start -> Preferences -> LXQt Settings -> Session Settings -> Autostart`. Deselect `nm-tray` and select `Network` (that refers to `nm-applet`). Restart or log-out for the changes to take place. In the taskbar, right-clicking on the Wifi symbol lets you create a new Openconnect connection that asks for your credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to fix this issue. So, in general the problem was because my network manager didn't ask for a password while I tried to connect to VPN. And basically it's very easy to fix it, you just need to write this command in terminal (from manual):

```
nmcli con up id <VPN_name> --ask changing <VPN_name>
```

With the actual VPN-name. Or:

```
nm-applet
```

Then you need to reboot your PC and after that try to connect to VPN again, it must ask for a password now.

Comment: https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/G/AdvancedNetworking.html