# NetworkManager(nm-tray) network manager nm-tray connection lost no longer connected to 802-3-ethenet

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, network-manager, connection, network-bridge

My Lubuntu frequently popup this message, this doesn't mean to occur 100%, it usually occurs a period of time after booting, or it more likely occurs when the host win10 bootup from hibernation but not always the case:

> NetworkManager(nm-tray) network manager nm-tray connection lost no longer connected to 802-3-ethenet 'Wired Connection 1'

**Environment**:

```
Host OS:  Win 10
Guest OS: Lubuntu 20.04
VM:       VirtualBox 6.1.28
```

'Wired Connection 1' is a Bridged Adapter which attached to a WiFi device in host system. Another NAT adapter is also configured to the Lubuntu, which never reports errors.

The "lost connection" issue can be recovered by Disable Networking then Enable Networking, or by rebooting Lubuntu.

I have ever done some search, I try to apply the answer from [I can't connect to VPN, NetworkManager says "(nm-tray): Connection lost no longer connected to vpn" on Lubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287340/i-cant-connect-to-vpn-networkmanager-says-nm-tray-connection-lost-no-longe). Network totally doesn't work when I switch from nm-tray to nm-applet.

How to fix this issue? Or how can I get more debug information such as detailed logs to address the issue?